# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Computation

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var yourScore: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var totalScore: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let score1: Int = yourScore.text.toInt()!
    let score2: Int = totalScore.text.toInt()!
    let mistakes = score2 - score1
    let scoreFinal = ((((score2 / 2) - mistakes)*23)/score2)+75
    labelText.text = "\(scoreFinal)"
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Something is wrong with my code. Is it because of data types or something? When I load the application, it just opens fine but when the button is pressed, the app crashes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2i5Z.png

Comment: Find the line where it crashes and paste the error here.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `buttonPressed` and examine your `IBOutlet` s - my guess is one or more of them is nil

Comment: @iosDev82 It crashes right here:         labelText.text = "\(scoreFinal)"

Comment: @Paulw11 Could you please explain what you said?

Comment: Search for instructions on using breakpoints and the debugger in Xcode. They are very useful tools that can let you see what is happening in your program.

Comment: From the breakpoint, I have identified that the problem is really that line.

Comment: @Paulw11 What do you think I should do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could safely unwrap the values with `if let`:

```
if let score1 = yourScore.text.toInt() {
    if let score2 = totalScore.text.toInt() {
        let mistakes = score2 - score1
        let scoreFinal = ((((score2 / 2) - mistakes)*23)/score2)+75
        labelText.text = "\(scoreFinal)"
    } else {
        // no valid score2
    }
} else {
    // no valid score1
}
```

Comment: Hi Ericd, thanks for your reply. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: On which line is the error happening? Maybe your IBOutlet is also nil.

Comment: It crashes right here: labelText.text = "(scoreFinal)"

Comment: See @paulw11's comment about breakpoints. With breakpoints you can check *which* of your property is nil or is having a problem.

Comment: Most likely, your problem is related to your `labelText` outlet.

Comment: I have used breakpoints and I have labelText is really the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Check that your outlet is properly connected to its object in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

While unwrapping, you can't just willy nilly use the values. Before unwrapping you have to check if the current value is nil. If it's not nil, then you can safely unwrap the text.